# SUSY - using fractions for the gutter

Tags: sass, compass, susy, libsass

When I setup my grid with a map in susy

```
$susy: (
  columns: 12,
  gutters: 1/4,
  math: fluid,
  output: float,
  gutter-position: inside,
);
```

It does not like the gutter as a fraction and I have had to change this to a decimal. No big deal but why if the documentation says this is how to do it does it break?

http://susy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/settings/

I am using libsass with compass-mixins installed via bower but am pretty sure this happened when I ran with compass.

Comment: Is there an error?  What is the error?

Comment: It does not compile.

Comment: It doesn't "not compile" without an error, so what is the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known bug in libsass, and has already been fixed - but that fix has not trickled down into `node-sass` yet.